# Trying to create a 64-bit installer from an existing 32-bit installer.(Makemsi)

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

I am trying to create a 64-bit installer from an existing 32-bit installer.(Makemsi)
When installing 64-bit on machine with 32-bit already installed, the 32-bit files in the 
program folder are not removed and 64-bit files are not installed. When installing 32-bit 
on a machine with 64-bit already installed  it removes 64-bit files and installs 32-bit 
files.

Can anyone help me in understanding what happens When installing 64-bit on machine with 
32-bit already installed.

Comment: Please show what you've done so far.

Comment: If you haven't changed the ProductCode between the 32-bit and 64-bit then not much will happen - it might just do a repair that looks a bit like an install. You also have not indicated if you are attempting an upgrade or not. There's also the issue of whether the component ids are identical for the 32-bit components that are in both the 32-bit and 64-bit setups.